# exporting a plugin as a product: No application id has been found

Tags: eclipse, product

im trying to export a sample plugin as a product in eclipse but every time i try to run the product i get the following error:

```
!SESSION 2012-07-11 10:17:35.813 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product test.product
Command-line arguments:  -product test.product -data /home/arvin/workspace/sample/../runtime-test.product(5) -dev file:/home/arvin/workspace/sample/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/test.product (5)/dev.properties -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2012-07-11 10:17:36.351
!MESSAGE Product test.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-11 10:17:36.395
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Comment: Did you create a .product file in your plugin and export it as a product?

Comment: Similar Question was asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426346/exporting-a-plugin-as-a-product-no-application-id-has-been-found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is because that Iv'e forgotten to add my plugins to dependencies. I've just added the required plugin from org.eclipse but I should also my own plugins to it.

Answer (score 6):

Dependencies issue; Goto "Run->Run Configurations...", Select "Plug-ins" tab and click the "Add Reuired Plugin" button

Comment: Do you know which plugin needs added?

Comment: I faced similar issue. However, when I ran the product via SWTBot (Functional/Unit Testing Library for Eclipse UI: www.eclipse.org/swtbot), it would run without throwing these errors.

Open the product file in Dependencies tab and press `Add Required Plugins` ...if there are any missing dependencies, Eclipse will add it for you. If you are using some version control system, then compare the .product file to see what were the dependencies missing.
Run the product

This fixed my issue

Eclipse version: Helios or 3.6, Win 32